# Installing and uninstalling a minimal desktop without autostart on a CLI-only Linux

Tags: command-line, desktop-environment

I'd like to install a preferably x-based desktop environment (can be gnome or something else, it's just that x is installed by default on my distro) on a CLI-only install. I'd like for it to be uninstallable afterwards and to have minimal to no effect on the boot process and overall system (other than what I will do myself in it obviously, I still want to be able to install stuff for example). So it's better if it doesn't autostart and I have to manually run it from the CLI myself.

I figure the autostart fear I have stem from it happening on desktop-based distros but I assume it wouldn't autostart when installed manually from commands right ?

To give a bit of background, this is running on a Raspberry Pi. The idea is to temporarily install a desktop environment to cleanly run the install process of games I'll run through box86/box64 (be it for GOG games or Steam, some parts of the process my do some funky things when using only xinit or may even outright not work) then uninstall the environment and run the games from Pegasus Fronted via commands.

From my research, installing the environment itself isn't hard, I just couldn't find much documentation on :

- whether it autostarts when installed (which I'd rather not)
- whether it makes a lot of important system changes that will affect the system post uninstallation
- whether the installation will go smoothly and not affect whatever autologin and autostart process I already have in place
- which environment is the most minimal to install. I don't want it to install any "basic" app like Minesweeper/card games, a notepad/text editor, browser that won't be automatically removed once the environment is uninstalled (anything that uninstalls with it I'm fine)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need to install a desktop environment for that – you could just use X forwarding to your desktop/laptop computer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is X forwarding still possible with a Windows client like putty or similar ?
Also wouldn't that cause issues (similar to what I initially fear with kernel mode running x apps) with installers sometimes opening and closing new windows fast ?
Edit : to be clear I'm referring to when they sometimes open new windows to install stuff like dependencies or things like that

Comment: Yes, it's possible. No, it should not pose any problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah I just discovered thanks to you that Putty is able to forward X11 no problem, so thanks for that. Gonna try that with the already existing softs and games installed, see how that works. As far as new windows go, does that mean new windows will just be created as well ? Or will the other windows run silently in the background ? (could be an issue with those requiring interaction but that's not so common anyway)